# I have 2 wifi cards and want to route all web trafic through 1

Tags: networking, wireless

I have 2 wifi network cards. One card connects to my development LAN with unprotected IoT devices on it that shouldn't touch the Internet. The other card connects to my Internet router.

The two routers use 2 separate local IP ranges (192.168.1.x and 192.168.254.x).

I need to use one card to SSH into local ips on the 192.168.1.x range and then route all other traffic through the 192.168.254.x range.

EDIT: Here is the output of `route -n` when both networks are connected

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.254.254 0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp3s0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    601    0        0 wlx74da385c8fd1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp3s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlx74da385c8fd1
192.168.254.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp3s0
```

And the result of `ip add show`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 69:69:69:69:69:69 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.254.72/24 brd 192.168.254.255 scope global dynamic wlp3s0
       valid_lft 86331sec preferred_lft 86331sec
    inet6 fe80::e941:eed1:eb36:787f/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlx74da385c8fd1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 96:96:96:96:96:96 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.254/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic wlx74da385c8fd1
       valid_lft 86398sec preferred_lft 86398sec
    inet6 fe80::426c:9f0:b6d7:31a8/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Please post the result of `ip add show`

Comment: Ok. I did that.

Comment: Are you suing a firewall with this setup?

Comment: No. I do not have a firewall.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, and it is really easy to do using Ubuntu's wifi gui.

For the following explanation My_Network_SSID = the isolated IoT network. There might be two networks of the same name because you may have established connections with both cards and so a configuration has been made for each card. Ubuntu just appended a 1 at the end of the correct SSID (because the network card I want to configure was the second card to access that SSID).

I click WIFI_SYMBOL->Edit Connections->My_Network_SSID->Edit->IPV4 Settings->Click "Method:" dropdown and select Automaic (DHCP) Adresses Only.

This will stop DNS requests from being routed through that router.

While still on IPV4 Settings, click Routes(Button on bottom right)->Use this connection only for resources on the network(Check Box). Then save the settings and connect!